# python normalizing fixing string

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a log file that contain unstructured entries like this

```
[roomID=19, description=ZZZZ, requesterCode=20, result=-1, errors=[[code=1, text=XXXXXXrequestID=/1540], flow=10:1] [remote=0.0.0.0, host=xxx]
[roomID=19, description=ZZZZ, requesterCode=20, result=-1, errors=[[code=2, text=XXXXXX., [code=2, text=XXXXXXrequestID=/1551], flow=12:3]
```

As you can see the 'errors' value starts with '[' but it does not has closing which makes it harder to parse

What I want to do is to clean only 'errors' part and fix it like this:
Replcaing '[]' with '{}' and removing duplicate keys from errors so i can read it into python dict

```
[roomID=19, description=ZZZZ, requesterCode=20, result=-1, errors={code=1, text=XXXXXX, requestID=/1540}, flow=10:1] [remote=0.0.0.0, host=xxx]
[roomID=19, description=ZZZZ, requesterCode=20, result=-1, errors={code=2, text=XXXXXX., requestID=/1551}, flow=12:3]
```

I'm not good in python but I try with this poor code. I need your kind help to do it in efficient way.

```
def fix(str):
    str = str.replace('errors=[[', 'errors={')
    ..
    return str
```

Thank you very much

Comment: what is `XXXXXX`? of which characters is made of?

Comment: This is english chars but it can contain numbers, and special chars

Comment: in the 2nd case: what happen to code2=... and text=XXXX? since there are 2 text=XXX which one is the survivor?

Comment: in the first case it's from the original logs which contain some duplicates. I try to remove it in the 2nd case, but it's not very important to remove duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html) from the standard library you can perform more complex text manipulations.

The important is to identify properly your patterns.

- `=[[` --> `={`
- `[`  -->
- `]`   --> `}`

Of course, they can be done more robusts.

```
import re

log = """roomID=19, description=ZZZZ, requesterCode=20, result=-1, errors=[[code=1, text=XXXXXXrequestID=/1540], flow=10:1
roomID=19, description=ZZZZ, requesterCode=20, result=-1, errors=[[code=2, text=XXXXXX., [code=2, text=XXXXXXrequestID=/1551], flow=12:3"""

mapping = {1: '={', 2: ' ', 3: '}'}
regex = r'(=\[\[)|(\s\[)|(\])' # r stands for raw string not for regex!

log_new = re.sub(regex, lambda match: mapping[match.lastindex], log)

print(log_new)
```

Answer to the EDITED question

```
log = """[roomID=19, description=ZZZZ, requesterCode=20, result=-1, errors=[[code=1, text=XXXXXXrequestID=/1540], flow=10:1] [remote=0.0.0.0, host=xxx]
[roomID=19, description=ZZZZ, requesterCode=20, result=-1, errors=[[code=2, text=XXXXXX., [code=2, text=XXXXXXrequestID=/1551], flow=12:3]"""

import re

mapping = {1: '', 2:'{code', 3: '}, '}
regex = r'(\[code=\d+,\s)|(\[+code)|(\],\s)'

log_new = re.sub(regex, lambda match: mapping[match.lastindex], log)

# split text into list
log_new = re.sub(r'(text=.+?)(requestID=)', r'\1, \2' , log_new)

print(log_new)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I forgot to mention that The input are between [ and ]. Please see my modified question, I appreciate if you can have another look and help with the format.

Comment: that's why I mentioned the importance of _identify_ the patterns!

Comment: You're right I should have reviewed it carefully. I appreciate your help

Comment: This is english chars but it can contain numbers, and special chars

Comment: Actually, I'm working on creating a parser for unstructured logs. Do you do freelance? kttp [AT] protonmail [DOT] com

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please, Do you do freelance? kttp [AT] protonmail [DOT] com

Comment: ...and don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question!

Comment: Hi, I'm waiting for you. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm waiting for you. Thanks